# Git "stucked" branch

Tags: git, version-control, dvcs

I'm having problem pushing my branch to the remote repository. Git returns me an error:
`error: dst refspec refs/heads/XXX matches more than one.` When I run `git ls-remote` it only shows me one `XXX` branch though! (I've tried to delete the branch using `git push origin :refs/heads/XXX` as well with the same result)

We've faced this issue more than once in more than one Git repositories. What we did previously was to clone the repositories and the "stucked" branch was gone from the cloned repositories.

I'm wondering if there is any alternative solutions to solve this issue without have to resort to re-clone the repository. Git version is 1.7.XX.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

As described in this [blog post](http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2013/06/13/git-having-a-branchtag-with-the-same-name-error-dst-refspec-matches-more-than-one/), make sure you don't have a tag with the same name as your branch.
If that is the case, you can delete it in the upstream repo:

```
git push origin :refs/tags/XXX
```

The alternative, [described in answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9382344/6309), is to push the branch explicitly (refspec set for both source and destination)

```
git push origin refs/heads/XXX:refs/heads/XXX
```

Comment: I don't have tags with the same name. Yea, tried the full refspec as well with no luck.

Comment: @user2507946 You don't have a local tag named XXX as well? Try a `git tag -d XXX`

Comment: @user2507946 and on the server itself, can you have access to that repo (which is the one cloned) and see if there is any tag `XXX` with the same name as the branch?

Comment: no, there are no duplicate tags. in the end, we re-clone the repo and somehow that solves it :(